# convert Future[MyType] into Future[Option[MyType]]

Tags: scala

I have a Future[MyType] which is produced by an api call across the wire. If the api call fails because the wrong data was sent it just throws an Exception (not very helpful but nothing I can do about it.

So I want to check with a try / catch and return a Future[Option[MyType]] like this:

```
def myfunc(name:String):Future[Option[MyType]] = {
  try {
    val d:Future[MyType] = apiCall(name) //returns a Future[MyType]

    ???? Convert d into future(Some(MyType))

  } catch {
    future(None)
  }

}
```

Thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This really depends on where exactly the exception is being thrown.  If `apiCall` is throwing an exception *before* it creates the `Future`, you could map the `Future` to wrap the value in an `Option`:

```
try {
  val d: Future[Option[MyType]] = apiCall(name).map{result => Some(result)}
} catch {
  case t: Throwable => Future.successful(None)
}
```

However I don't think this is the best way to go about this, since you are effectively losing information as to why the api call failed.  `Option` is generally not a great solution for indicating an error has occurred.  I think a better solution would be to return a future containing the exception:

```
try {
  val d:Future[MyType] = apiCall(name)
} catch {
  case t: Throwable => Future.failed(t)
}
```

The reason for this is whatever code you have handling the future is going to have to handle exceptions inside the future already, so this will keep all your error handling in one place.

If the exception is being thrown *inside* the `Future`, wrapping `apiCall` in a try/catch block won't help since the exception is not thrown synchronously, so you can use `map` and `recover`:

```
val d: Future[Option[MyType]] = apiCall(name).map{Some(_)}.recover{
  case t: Throwable => None
}
```

Comment: great advice, I'm not sure where the error is thrown..I will examine further. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: Don't catch `Throwable` but instead catch `NonFatal`. Also, if apiCall returns a Future, I would not expect it to throw anything but instead return a failed Future.